# VerifyError: Error #1014: Class spark.components.supportClasses::ItemRenderer could not be found

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flex4

I have a small code in flex that needs a very small fix, change in text field. I have never done flex programming. I downloaded the "FlashBuilder 4.7" Built a small test application. I tried to run it as Webapplication. A web page open but nothing gets displayed. Then I downloaded the FlashPlayer debugger and opened the swf file and I got the error

```
VerifyError: Error #1014: Class spark.components.supportClasses::ItemRenderer could not be found.
```

I am sure this is the cause why my application is not showing up in the browser. As you can see from the image I have attached, I have included the spark components. Have tried all possible ways that I can think of to solve this and even googled it no luck. So turning to this group to see if I can get some help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    width="100%" height="100%">

    <s:Label text="My First Flex Application"/>
</s:Application>
```

And my project setup
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the flash debugger, I was using the swf file generated in the bin-debug folder and that was giving me this error. What I did was I went to FLashBuilder -> Project -> "Export Release Build..." This created the swf file in the bin-releae folder. When I run this swf in the flash debugger, it works fine. Not sure why the debug version is not running.